# Cannot call value of non-function type 'UITableView?' in UITapGestureRecognizer method

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

My table tap gesture recogniser calls a method that displays a message informing that no row values are present, and some should be added. This happens when user touches anywhere inside the table view.

The error is in tableTapped inside the if let statement.

I've tried deleting and recreating the tableView in story builder. Also tried 'homework' instead of 'tableView' and the parameter name. Also tried removing 'self.' before 'tableView'.

I have this exact same method on another class, and it works fine so I guess there's something different about the class it's not working in. I just can't pinpoint it!

```
import UIKit

class homeworkViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var clear: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var all: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var chosen: UIButton!

    var languages = [String]()
    var chosenLanguage = String()
    var chosenLanguageRemoved = false
    var homeworkWords = [String]()
    var chosenLanguageEnabled = false
    let wordString = "words"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .play, target: self, action: #selector(test))

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tableTapped))
        self.tableView.backgroundView = UIView()
        self.tableView.backgroundView?.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @objc func tableTapped(tap:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let location = tap.location(in: self.tableView)
        let path = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location)
        if let indexPathForRow = path {
            self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPathForRow)
        } else {
            if homeworkWords.isEmpty == true {
                let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Add Homework!", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default)
                ac.addAction(okAction)
                present(ac, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func chosen(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Use Chosen Language", message: "Add or clear choosen language words to quickly set homework.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        // add user actions, "Cancel" to abort
        if chosenLanguageEnabled == false {
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Set", style: .default, handler: chosenLanguage))
        }
        if chosenLanguageEnabled == true {
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Clear", style: .default, handler: clearChosenLanguage))
        }
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))
    }

    func chosenLanguage(action: UIAlertAction!) {
        homeworkWords.removeAll()
        if let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.co.uk.tirnaelectronics.hyperpolyglot.todayview") {
            if var savedWords = defaults.object(forKey: "\(chosenLanguage)\(wordString)") as? [String] {
                print("savedWords in chosenLanguage in homeworkViewController are: \(savedWords)")
                homeworkWords = savedWords
                saveWords()
                savedWords.removeAll()
                chosenLanguageEnabled = true
                print("chosenLanguageEnabled in chosenLanguage method in homeworkViewController is: \(chosenLanguageEnabled)")
                print("homeworkWords in chosenLanguage method in homeworkViewController are: \(homeworkWords)")
                print("savedWords after clear all in chosenLanguage method in homeworkViewController are: \(savedWords)")
            }
        }
    }

    func clearChosenLanguage(action: UIAlertAction!) {
        homeworkWords.removeAll()
        saveWords()
        chosenLanguageEnabled = false
    }

    @IBAction func allWords(_ sender: UIButton) {
        homeworkWords.removeAll()
        for language in languages {
            if let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.co.uk.tirnaelectronics.hyperpolyglot.todayview") {
                if var savedWords = defaults.object(forKey: "\(language)\(wordString)") as? [String] {
                    print("savedWords array is: \(savedWords)")
                    homeworkWords.append(contentsOf: savedWords)
                    saveWords()
                    savedWords.removeAll()
                    print("allWords method homeworkWords are: \(homeworkWords)")
                    print("allWords savedWords after clear all: \(savedWords)")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in

            self.homeworkWords.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.saveWords()
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
            tableView.endUpdates()
            // delete item at indexPath
            if self.homeworkWords.isEmpty == true {
                self.clear.isEnabled = false
                self.clear.alpha = 0.25
            }
        }

        delete.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.isHighlighted = true
        }
        return [delete]
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //print("In cellForRowAt function")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "homework", for: indexPath)

        let word = homeworkWords[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = word.capitalized

        //print(cell)
        return cell
    }

    func loadHomeworkWords() {
        if let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.co.uk.tirnaelectronics.hyperpolyglot.todayview") {
            if var savedHomeWorkWords = defaults.object(forKey: "homeworkWords") as? [String] {
                print("savedLanguages array is: \(savedHomeWorkWords)")
                homeworkWords.removeAll()
                homeworkWords = savedHomeWorkWords
                savedHomeWorkWords.removeAll()
                print("savedHomeWorkWords after removeAll: \(savedHomeWorkWords)")
                print("loadHomeworkWords homeworkWords are: \(homeworkWords)")
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        loadHomeworkWords()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func saveWords() {
        if let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.co.uk.tirnaelectronics.hyperpolyglot.todayview") {
            defaults.set(homeworkWords, forKey: "homeworkWords")
                print("saveWords homeworkWords homeworkViewController are: \(homeworkWords)")
        }
    }
}
```

I expect to see a UIAlertAction message telling the user they need to add some table row values by tapping on either the 'All words' button or 'chosen language' button, if there are no values in any of the table rows.

Instead I get the pre-compile error message:

Cannot call value of non-function type 'UITableView?'

Comment: Why are you calling a delegate method? What is suppose to do `if let indexPathForRow = path {
            self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPathForRow)
        }`?

Comment: Why did you add a tap gesture to the table view? A table view already handles row selection.

Comment: In addition to what others have said, you haven't declared `didSelectRowAt` yet.

Comment: @Sweeper Table view will handle row selection, but when no rows are populated it won't do that handling (as far as I know, I could be wrong). I need to tell user that they should enter row values when no table rows are populated, instead of tapping on an empty table! Maybe I didn't make it clear enough in my question? Sweeper's answer prompted me to check my other class' this method works in, and didSelectRowAt had been declared in them. That is the correct answer.

Comment: Okay, I see what you are trying to do here, but from a design point of view, why would somewhere without a cell be tappable? Why would a user even tap on somewhere without a cell on a table view? I suggest you use something like [EmptyDataSet](https://github.com/Xiaoye220/EmptyDataSet-Swift) to show a message when the table view is empty. You can also configure it to do something when the empty data set view is tapped.

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you, I'll look into it.